# Projecting a Positive Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, matrix-decomposition

If a matrix is positive-definite, is its projection on a subspace positive-definite as well?

The question concerns linear operators in general. Let $O$ be a positive-definite operator and $P$ the operator that projects into a given subspace. Is $P\circ O \circ P$ also positive-definite?

Comment: The subspace is invariant? Otherwise the projections isn't really well defined I think..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption of positive-definiteness of $O$, we cannot guarantee that $POP$ is positive-definite.  For example, consider

$$
O=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} , \qquad
P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However we can show a slightly weaker statement:

> If $O$ is positive-semidefinite and $P$ is a projection, then $POP$ is positive-semidefinite.

To see this, let $V$ be an inner product space with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, let $O\in L(V)$ be positive-semidefinite, and let $P$ be a projection (i.e. a self-adjoint idempotent).  Then for any $x\in V$ we have
$$ \langle x,POPx\rangle=\langle P^*x,OPx\rangle =\langle Px,OPx\rangle=\langle(Px),O(Px)\rangle\geq 0.$$
and thus $POP$ is positive-semidefinite.

---

**EDIT**  In fact,the same argument shows a slightly stronger statment.  Since idempotency of the projection wasn't necessary, we have

> If $O$ is positive-semidefinite and $T$ is self-adjoint, then $TOT$ is positive-semidefinite.

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is symmetric (orthogonal projector), then $POP$ is non-negative definite since $a' POP a = (Pa)'O (Pa) \geq 0$.